# GREP + REGEX not working as I expect

Tags: grep, arch-linux, regular-expression

I'm trying to get the output from ls /dev to match 'tty' that ends with numbers between 1-4.

So from:

```
tty5
tty4
tty2
tty6
tty1
```

Should match:

```
tty4
tty2
tty1
```

The regexp

```
"\s([tty]+[0-4])\s"
```

works in [RegExr](https://regexr.com/).

I've tried using this with grep:

```
ls /dev | grep -E \s([tty]+[0-4])\s

ls /dev | grep -E \s([tty]\+\[0-4])\s

ls /dev | grep -Ex \s([tty]+[0-4])\s

ls /dev | grep -P \s([tty]+[0-4])\s
```

as I've read in other posts, still I can't make it work.

Comment: When *do* `grep` and `regex` work as you expect?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The reason it isn't matching is because you are looking for whitespace (`\s`) before the string `tty` and at the end of your match. That never happens here since `ls` will print one entry per line. Note that `ls` is not the same as `ls | command`. When the output of `ls` is piped, that activates the `-1` option causing `ls` to only print one entry per line. It will work as expected if you just remove those `\s`:

```
ls /dev | grep -E '([tty]+[0-4])'
```

However, that will also match all sorts of things you don't want. That regex isn't what you need at all. The `[ ]` make a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). The expression `[tty]+` is equivalent to `[ty]+` and will match one or more `t` or `y`. This means it will match `t`,or `tttttttttttttttt`, or `tytytytytytytytytyt` or any other combination of one or both of those letters. Also, the parentheses are pointless here, they make a [capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) but you're not using it. What you want is this:

```
$ ls /dev | grep '^tty[0-4]$'
tty0
tty1
tty2
tty3
tty4
```

Note how I added the `$` there. That's so the expression only matches `tty` and then *one* number, one of 1, 2, 3 or 4 until the end of the line (`$`).

Of course, the safe way of doing this that avoids all of [the dangers of parsing `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is to use globs instead:

```
$ ls /dev/tty[0-4]
/dev/tty0  /dev/tty1  /dev/tty2  /dev/tty3  /dev/tty4
```

or just

```
$ echo /dev/tty[0-4]
/dev/tty0 /dev/tty1 /dev/tty2 /dev/tty3 /dev/tty4
```

Comment: Great answer. Out of curiosity, in your regex solution (before you get into why you should use globbing instead -- which you totally should!), why not start the regex with `^`?

Comment: @jakerobb um, because I didn't think to do it! I should have though, you're quite right. Thanks :)

Comment: also `/dev/tty{1..4}`  :)

Comment: @Eevee that depends on the shell you're using.

Comment: @Eevee yes, not only is that not portable, it also prints error messages if any of those don't exist (with `ls`) and will print everything regardless of whether it exists with `echo`.

Comment: @terdon which may or may not be what you want!  but imo it's more appropriate for counting — wildcards get a little messier if you want, say, ttys 0 through 13

Comment: If the OP wants to have each file printed on its own line, (s)he could use `printf %s\\n /dev/tty[1-4]`. It's just like the echo command from your answer, but with newlines instead of spaces.

Comment: Also, do you really need the "-E" in `ls /dev/* | grep -E '^tty[0-4]'`? It seems to me that said switch doesn't do anything that the OP needs.

Comment: @TSJNachos117 what makes you think the OP would want that? But yes, indeed, that is one way of doing it. As for the `-E`, you're quite right, I don't need it. I just copied it from the OP, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what the OP wants. I just though I might point out that option, since it would give the same output as most of the other options in your answer.

Answer (score 7):

That regex seems a little overcomplicated. Also, you should be using quoting!

```
$ ls /dev | grep -E "tty[1-4]$"
tty1
tty2
tty3
tty4
```

However, you should definitly read this: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: That's great thanks, I'm still curious why it works in Regexr and not in grep -P, yeah forgot to write quotations in the post, I use them. Thanks I will have a look at that link.

Comment: Most regex engines are a little bit different from each other. Even regexr has support for "Javascript" and "PCRE" variants in the top right menu. Also grep supports two different variants through `grep` and `grep -E` (which is same as `egrep`). All of these four are different to some extent. `grep -P` is the same as PCRE though.

Comment: I'd advise single quotes instead of double quotes in this answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
bash-4.2$ ls -l /dev | grep -o "tty[1-4]$"
tty1
tty2
tty3
tty4


bash-4.2$ ls -l /dev | awk '/tty[1-4]$/{print $NF}'
tty1
tty2
tty3
tty4

bash-4.2$ output=$(ls /dev); echo "${output}" | grep "tty[1-4]$"
tty1
tty2
tty3
tty4
```

Comment: Why use `-l`? That just makes it more complicated (forcing you to use the non-standard `-o` and `print $NF` instead of `print`) for no benefit. And why would you store it in a variable to then print the same variable again?